# Какую технологию выбрать?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, java

Есть написанная нами программа на Delphi, она служит для графического отображения информации о дороге. Сама дорога в ней выглядит как несколько горизонтальных баров, цвета которых определяют свойства дороги на заданном участке, свойства дороги для каждого участка хранятся в БД, есть возможность редактирования свойств и участков.

Сейчас хотим переделать её на более современной платформе. Выбираем на чём делать. Нужно, чтобы система функционировала и через браузер (ПК и мобильные устройства) с доступом к удалённой БД, и как локальное приложение с возможностью выбора - брать данные из удалённой БД или из локального файла, предварительно загруженного из браузера. Хочется не делать двойную работу, поэтому интересны прежде всего технологии, способные обеспечить использование одних и тех же классов и в браузерной версии, и в локальной. Возможно такое? Или придётся вести параллельную разработку сайта и клиента?

Ориентируемся на C#, потому что недавно попробовали и понравилось, но, так как учиться придётся с нуля, рассматриваем ВСЕ возможные варианты.

Silverlight? WPF? Java? Они нам помогут?

Comment: Мне кажется лучший выбор будет для вас сделать серверную часть на ASP.NET MVC или ASP.NET Web Api - это нужно будет сделать один раз, а потом прикрутить туда клиент на WPF, потом и браузерный клиент если нужно будет.
Сервер можно и на Java, но десктопный клиент в любом случае удобнее, быстрее и красивее делать на WPF. Кстати почему некоторые пишут что Java проще шарпа я не знаю, в Джаве нет кучи возможностей, которые есть в шарпе, которые нехило увеличивают удобство разработки и читабельность кода.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хм, чтобы показывало и в браузере, и было приложение?

Предлагаю тогда, либо писать на **Java**

Или использовать связку **Silverlight** и **WPF**

**WPF** вообще хорош тем что предназначен для графических отображений, больше использует видеокарту.., а **Silverlight** можно встроить в сайт. При этом платформы одни и те же, так что классы можно будет и там и там использовать.

Comment: немного добавлю что WPF формы можно скомпилировать в браузерное приложение и запускать через браузер, тогда не надо будет заморачиваться с SilverLight, а просто использовать один и тоже код

Comment: Чему человек, знакомый с Delphi научится быстрей: WPF или Java?

Comment: Если можно всегда работать через браузер - это хорошо и тогда можно без клиента, но только, если не придётся устанавливать сервер на локал. Так можно WPF?

Comment: Java проще в изучении, чем WPF(C#), как мне кажется - за последний год программировал и на том и на другом.

Comment: согласен, на WPF сложнее, у меня даже с C# (начинал на Delphi) туго шел переход на WPF, на Java я почти сразу все сообразил.

Comment: Будем делать на C#. На WinXP/7 WPF, а на вэбе, наверное, ASP.NET, JS и HTML5 - сегодня показывали чуваку с сертификатом :) он так посоветовал...
А может и будем использовать Silverlight - я с ним ещё побеседую...

Comment: ASP.NET, JS и HTML5 - тоже хороший выбор.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы все таки посоветовал начать с другого конца: не с того, что нравится, а с того что будет востребовано. WPF/Silverlight конечно замечательно, но рыночная доля WP7/8 что-то в районе 1-2% - фактически это усилия и деньги на ветер.

Если грубо то рынок смартфонов поделен 20% - iOS и еще 70% Андроид, 10% на все остальное: WPF, Symbian, BlackBerry и проч. экзотика. Есть небольшие вариации по странам, континентам, но в целом [картина именно такая](http://www.engadget.com/2013/01/29/strategy-analytics-android-70-percent-share/).

Единственная известная мне технология покрывающая и десктоп и iOS и Android - это HTML5. Применительно к среде разработки это [PhoneGap](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap) - кстати он покрывает также и WP7 (по WP8 привет от Билла Гейтса).

Есть конечно в целом большие нарекания по производительности HTML5 решений, в частности Facebook выкинул в свалку своего клиента для Android и iPhone переписав их под нативные приложения. Но тем не менее - имеет смысл попробовать на Phonegap.

Если надумаете писать под десктоп и Android - то тут без вариантов - только Java. C# вам тут не помощник.

Comment: Можно под Android на Mono, но не очень комфортно будет. Я не трогал это и мне кажется там таится еще некоторое количество багов, которые если начнут появляться в проекте, то решение искать долго, если оно есть конечно.

Comment: @Barmaley о, пошла высокоинтеллектуальная беседа специалистов... Ждём-с новых епитетов.

Comment: @Barmaley, я представляю ситуацию. Большой проект, непонятные баги да и сроки поджимают. Это худший сценарий, но и он возможен:)

Comment: Начальство выбрало WPF, завтра скажу им насчёт Java. 
 
Писать под мобильные устройства приложения мы не собираемся, на них предполагается работа через браузер с удалённой БД только при наличии подключения к интернету. 
 
"Клиент" имеющий возможность брать данные также из локального файла нужен только под Windows xp/7 
 
Но. Я вот думаю, напишет программист клиент на C# WPF, а смогу ли я потом, используя его код, собрать сайт на C# ASP.NET? Собственно, вот в чём вопрос. 
 
А также, можете-ли вы посоветовать что-то лучше и быстрее в освоении? (Насчёт Java я уже понял)

Comment: На счет WPF порадовали:)
На счет собрать сайт - мне кажется, что да. И там и там C#. Вы возьмете всю логику реализованную в классах и обернете ее в ASP.net.

Comment: @Barmaley Я понимаю, что ответ дан более трёх лет назад, но для всех популярных мобильных платформ уже существует Xamarin, позволяющий писать на C#. Плюс также существует Unity3D решение.
Поэтому C# "не помощник" — это уже нет.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сделать все на Java (для работы в браузере можно использовать, скажем, GWT/SmartGWT).

Причем, локальную версию тогда можно вообще не делать. Просто в этом случае все три основные компонента (интерфейс пользователя (он всегда в браузере), сервер приложений (видимо Tomcat) и СУБД) будут установлены локально.

Comment: SmartGWT, он весьма на любителя. Второй год с ним маемся )

Answer (score 0):

С# - (WP7,WP8, + Android,IOS(Mono)) - мобильные платформы, все что возможно для этого инструмента. И Web(ASP.NET). Настольные приложения WPF. Под вебом я мог не так понять, если что не судите строго.
Java - Настольные это Swing, + Android + web на ней можно делать разными способами.

На счет Silverlight я не осведомлен.

Answer (score 0):

API своего сайта я бы советовал написать на ASP.NET WebAPI либо на ASP.NET Core WebAPI.

Затем код вашего клиента может быть разным.

Но можно исходить из того, что поддерживается везде.
HTML5-решения может и неплохи, но обычно с производительностью проблемы. Я бы посмотрел в сторону OpenGL. Поэтому можно для всего выбрать Unity3D и на нём писать [GUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.html), при этом можно выбирать C# или JavaScript.

---

Другой вариант:
Для Desktop-платформ, чтобы не писать разный код для Windows, Linux, Mac OS X можно было бы использовать что-то связанное с [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/). На момент написания ответа, это Windows.Forms и GTK#.
Для абсолютно всех мобильных платформ можно использовать Xamarin. Синтаксис представлений концептуально похож на WPF.